# Need help with bumblebee --------Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm new to ubuntu. I have a ACER R7 with intel and gt 750m and I'm pretty sure they are using optimus. However, after I install and run bumblebee, I always get this error:

```
legolas@Frog:~$ optirun firefox
[ 4306.969576] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
[ 4306.969674] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Where did I do wrong, is there any to correct it? I need the separate card to do my work. I tried other's solutions but still no luck.

Could you please give me some advice, or some test I could run?

I know the information is not enough to see what the problem is, but I don't know hot to test it and  give a detailed information. I'm glad to run any test that is helpful to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please provide /var/log/XOrg.o.log for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hi, There! thanks for the method. I tried all of them, but after the final reboot. I got black screen.....When I start, I saw Ubuntu icon and then totally black. is there anyway that I can fix this? really appreciate it! thanks